# Are Display Form FieldControls used in 2013 Custom Field Types?

Tags: 2013, custom-field-types, display-form, field-controls

When using a Custom Field Type that has a Field Control (provided by FieldRenderingControl), it seems that the Field Control isn't used when rendering data on the Display Form if the SPField.JSLink is defined.

In my case, the Field Control has previously worked in 2007 and 2010, but doesn't seem to be touched by the 2013 Display Form rendering (the data provided by the CSR context is always empty).

Comment: Cross-posted from a snubbed question here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointdevelopment/thread/a41ae9f8-b76b-4fae-8838-45747479e868